# When not to use hyphens in naming conventions for html/css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was reading an article that stated the dangers of using hyphens for naming conventions in web development (html/css/javascript).  I can't find the article anymore.  Can someone explain the problem with hyphens?  I think the article said that hyphens were automatically removed, so a name like red-square would be stored as redsquare...this is vague but all I can remember.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use hyphens for CSS ids and classes. Use camelCase for JavaScript in general, LeadingCaps for constructors, and CAPS for constants.

Comment: I can't think of any situations where a hyphen would be automatically removed.  Sounds like you were reading an article with bad advice.

Comment: @elclanrs more generally: conventions that are standard to the language

Comment: You may be thinking of the way that CSS properties with hyphens are represented in javascript in camelCase? (e.g. background-color becomes backgroundColor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hyphens for class names and IDs in HTML and JavaScript.  The hyphens are not removed.

You can't use hyphens for variable names in JavaScript because of a collision with the subtraction operator `-`.

Comment: You're right about *variable* names, but remember that you can use hyphens as *property* names, it just requires a little extra typing: `obj['prop-name']`

Comment: @josh3736 - You run the risk that you have a brain-snap and write obj.prop-name, though (which dies, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you use hyphens for a variable in JavaScript, it will parse the hyphen as a subtraction symbol.

For example, `num-line + extra` becomes `num - line + extra`.

It's fine to use hyphens for CSS and HTML markup. Use camelCase (myFavoriteVariable) or underscores (my_favorite_variable) for JavaScript.

The danger of a hyphen being "removed" is wrong as far as I'm aware.